# Implode or join multidimentional array with comma

Tags: php, arrays

I've array multidimentional ..

```
Array ( 
    [123] => Array ( [0] => 120 [1] => 200 [2] => 180 [3] => 130 ) 
    [124] => Array ( [0] => 150 [1] => 155 [2] => 160 [3] => 165 ) 
    [125] => Array ( [0] => 121 [1] => 120 [2] => 121 [3] => 121 ) 
)
```

I want to convert like this

```
120,200,180,130
150,155,160,165
121,120,121,121
```

how to code this guys ?

my code from stackoverflow too ..

```
 echo join("','", array_map(function ($data) { return $data[0]; }, $data))
```

but .. the output
`120, 150, 121` .. i want to get from 123

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: yes, i just follow from stackoverflow too.. 
echo join("','", array_map(function ($data) { return $data[0]; }, $data))

but .. the output ..

120, 150, 121 ..

i want to get from 123

Comment: Try google PHP [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) ...

Comment: *yes* Then show us your attempt

Comment: i just update the question , may you know or you can read my comment

Comment: @tara It's always good to show some effort and attempts so we know that you have tried something and we don't just do your work! And you were close :D

Comment: so sorry and thanks @Rizier123 for the answer ..

Comment: @tara np, your welcome! Have a nice day ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just go through each innerArray with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it and print it)

```
<?php

    $arr = [ 
            "123" => [120, 200, 180, 130], 
            "124" => [150, 155, 160, 165], 
            "125" => [121, 120, 121, 121] 
        ];


    array_map(function($v){
        echo implode(",", $v) . "<br />";
    }, $arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
120,200,180,130
150,155,160,165
121,120,121,121
```

Comment: wow thanks ! but anyway if you have time to answer .. what diffferent between implode and join ?

Comment: @tara: As you can read [here](http://php.net/function.join) the two functions are aliasses. So there is no difference, `implode` is more how php likes to name things.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate over all items in the `$arrs` and use `implode` to format every single array:

```
$arrs = Array ( 
    123 => Array ( 0 => 120, 1 => 200, 2 => 180, 3 => 130 ),
    124 => Array ( 0 => 150, 1 => 155, 2 => 160, 3 => 165 ),
    125 => Array ( 0 => 121, 1 => 120, 2 => 121, 3 => 121 ),
)
foreach($arrs as $arr) {
   echo implode(",",$arr)."\n";
}
```

`"\n"` means you append a new line in raw text. In case you want to use HTML for formatting, you should evidently use `<br/>`:

```
foreach($arrs as $arr) {
   echo implode(",",$arr).'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($yourArr as $key =>$val)
{
   $newArr[] = implode(",",$val);
}
foreach($newArr as $arr)
{
  echo $arr."<br>";
}
```

**output**

```
120,200,180,130
150,155,160,165
121,120,121,121
```

Comment: Why do you store the content first into another array?